# Scanf() works when I declare a string as char string[], but not when I declare it as char*

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int  main()

{
char t1string[20];
scanf("%s", t1string);
printf("%s\n", t1string);
printf("%c\n", t1string[4]);

char * t2string;
scanf("%s", t2string);
printf("%s\n", t2string);
printf("%c", t2string[4]);
}
```

Why does the scanf() not work in the second case (where string is declared as char *)?

Comment: This is not a string ```char * t2string;```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Pointer and strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804935/what-is-the-difference-between-pointer-and-strings)

Comment: Replace `char *t2string;` with either `char *t2string = malloc(20);` or `char *t2string = t1string;`. Read up to understand what each one does.

Comment: "where string is declared as char *" --> `char *` is a pointer.  A _string_ in not a pointer.  An array of characters could contain a _string_.

Answer (score 5):

Because before calling the scanf function, the corresponding space is not allocated to't2string', that is, the pointer of 't2string' does not point to a certain address

```c
 t2string = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
 // or
 char t1string[20];
 t2string = t1string;
```

Comment: Good insight, but what if i do this:                                                                                     
 char * t2string = "testagain";
scanf("%s", t2string);
printf("%s\n", t2string);
printf("%c", t2string[5]);
}                                      I would think the first declaration and assignment of "testagain" to t2string will pre-allocate memory, but the scanf() still does not work. I still need a bit more explanation here.

Comment: "testagain" is a const string.You can change this pointer, but you can not change the constant pointed to by this pointer

Comment: I tried it, it can work in msvc 2019 while can't in gcc 8.3. Now, I am also a little confused.

Answer (score 2):

Because `char[]` and `char*` are different.

Character array or `char[]` are block of data allocated by the compiler in the stack. The memory is allocated at the initialization and is done automatically by the compiler. It's position or size cannot be changed once it's allocated, as it is managed by compilers.

So

```
scanf("%s", t1string);
```

works as the compiler gives it the space to allocate.

On the other hand, a `char*` is just one variable which is used to store memory address to another block. All it does is initialize the memory to store the address. The actual memory block must be initialized manually. Because of that, it can be changed, freed, and reused by the user. Compiler does not manage these memories.

So,

```
scanf("%s", t2string);
```

doesn't work as you haven't allocated any memory to it. You have to allocate a memory block by using malloc(), calloc(), etc.

Comment: Good insight, but what if i do this: char * t2string = "testagain"; scanf("%s", t2string); printf("%s\n", t2string); printf("%c", t2string[5]); } I would think the first declaration and assignment of "testagain" to t2string will pre-allocate memory, but the scanf() still does not work. I still need a bit more explanation here. – blessedk 2 hours ago

Comment: `"testagain"` will allocate memory and printf will work. But `scanf()` doesn't work because the memory allocated for constant strings is read only.

Answer (score 0):

char* and char[] saves real string (not just get a address of literal)

that means you can change its value like

```
char[i] = 'a';
```

so, you should allocate space for '%s'

Moreover, you can see what is difference between String a = '...' and char[] a = '...';

char[] a = 'abc' will be changed to char[] a = { 'a', 'b', 'c'} in compile time(mutable)